# SQL - Taking the sum of two columns and then getting the average of each

Tags: sql, postgresql

Working on a problem and getting stuck on how to get the average once I've gotten the sum of two separate columns. What I can't seem to figure out is how to calculate the average price per page for each publisher as a new column. I tried simply wrapping the two columns with AVG in the select tab and got an error.

`SELECT pname as Publsiher, SUM(bprice) as totalprice, SUM(bpages) as totalpages
FROM publisher NATURAL JOIN book
GROUP BY pname;`

[sqlresults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tVt3.jpg)

Any tips or help would be appreciated! Sub select statement maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use division:

```
SELECT pname as Publsiher, SUM(bprice) as totalprice,
       SUM(bpages) as totalpages,
       SUM(bprice) as totalprice / SUM(pbages) as avgPerPace
FROM publisher NATURAL JOIN book
GROUP BY pname;
```

I would suggest that you replace the `NATURAL JOIN` with an explicit `USING` or `ON` clause.  `NATURAL JOIN` chooses the join keys based on the names of keys in the two tables (rather than using explicit foreign key relationships), so I think it is a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer does work, and his comments about Joins are spot on. But you need check that the average you get makes sense for the context you're using it in.

If you get divide the total price by the total number of pages, you'll get a figure that's weighted by the size of each book. If you get the price per page of each individual book, **then** average it, each book will have the same weighting.

```
WITH book AS
  (SELECT 'Publisher A' AS pname, 'Book 1' AS bname, 10 bprice, 1000 bpage FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 'Publisher A', 'Book 2', 10, 1000  FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 'Publisher A', 'Book 3', 10, 1000  FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 'Publisher A', 'Book 4', 10, 1000  FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT 'Publisher A', 'Book X', 1000, 1  FROM DUAL)

SELECT pname AS Publisher,
    Sum(bprice),
    Sum(bpage),
    Round(Sum(bprice) / Sum(bpage), 3) totalAvgPerPage,
    Avg(bprice / bpage) avgPerPagePerBook
FROM book
GROUP BY pname;
```

Results:

```
PUBLISHER     SUM(BPRICE)   SUM(BPAGE)  AVGPERPAGE  AVGPERPAGEPERBOOK
Publisher A   1040          4001        .26         200.008
```

In this ridiculous example most books are £0.01 per page, but Book X is £1000 per page. One average isn't affected as much as it's just a single page, but the other is affected greatly as it treats each book as equally valid.